# how to add a volume to an odoo that does not use volumes

Tags: odoo

Please, i already installed odoo by a method without using volumes, by the following command:

```
docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=odoo -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo --name db-old postgres:9.4
docker run -p 8066:8069 --name odoo-old --link db-old:db -t odoo:11
```

Now I'm using another instance of odoo that uses volume in its installation. Here is how I installed this new version of odoo:

```
sudo mkdir -p /volumes/docker/test_12/pg
sudo docker run -p 5001:5432 -itd -v /volumes/docker/test_12/pg:/var/lib/postgresql/data -e POSTGRES_USER=odoo -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo  -e POSTGRES_DB=postgres  --name db-new postgres:10.5
sudo mkdir -p /volumes/docker/test_12/addons
docker run -p 9012:8069 -itd -v /volumes/docker/test_12/addons:/mnt/extra-addons --name odoo-new --link db-new:db -t odoo:11
```

The problem is that I have a lot of data in the old odoo instance, I'm going to use the same odoo-old data in the new odoo-new instance, so remove odoo-old and keep odoo-new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use odoo backup to migrate to new odoo server and database server in new containers. Access odoo backup feature in old odoo with browser at url /web/database/manager and get the backup. Then access your new odoo with the same url and restore your file. It will restore both database and filestore to new server. This works with or without volumes in containers if the odoo version is same in old and new.

If you need to copy other file content from odoo server, you can use "docker cp" to copy files. In your situation I would first try with backup.

Your odoo version seems to be 11 for both old and new container images. Your directory name has hints of odoo 12. Make sure you are really using same odoo version. If you try to upgrade from odoo 11 to odoo 12, you need to upgrade your database content with e.g. OCA openupgrade (https://github.com/OCA/OpenUpgrade).

Comment: i can't restore database in odoo-new, so i have reinstalled odoo-new with the same version of postgres used in odoo-old, but also i can't restore database-old in odoo-new

Comment: What exact error are you getting? If you have pg version 10.5 on server but different pg client version in odoo container, it could result in error restoring.

Comment: thanks you it work but i need to use an other version of odoo and postgres